# Quasar drawer toggle status problems

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a basic SPA with two child components, a header and a side menu (left drawer).

From the header I have used a custom event to trigger the variable to be updated in the parent and this variable is then passed to the side menu via prop.

**Parent Component**

```
<MainHeader @toggleLeftDrawer="toggleLeftDrawer()"/>
<LeftDrawer :leftDrawerOpen="leftDrawerOpen" />

export default {
  components: { MainHeader, LeftDrawer },
  setup () {
    const leftDrawerOpen = ref(false)

    return {
      leftDrawerOpen,
      toggleLeftDrawer () {
        leftDrawerOpen.value = !leftDrawerOpen.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Header**

```
<q-btn dense flat round icon="menu" @click="toggleLeftDrawer" />

export default {
  setup (props, context) {
    const toggleLeftDrawer = () => {
      context.emit('toggleLeftDrawer')
    }
    return {
      toggleLeftDrawer
    }
  }
}
```

**Left Drawer**

```
<q-drawer
  show-if-above
  :model-value="leftDrawerOpen"
  side="left"
  :width="283"
  bordered
>
</q-drawer>

export default {
  props: ['leftDrawerOpen']
}
```

I have identified two problems/bugs with this setup of separating the code into components:

1. As the variable is initially defined with a value of false it takes two clicks of the "hamburger menu" to close the drawer. The 1st sets it to true (current state) and the 2nd sets it to false and hides the drawer
2. If the drawer is closed by clicking the "hamburger menu" the variable is set to false however if the drawer is closed by clicking the background the drawer does not close.

Comment: try without `show-if-above` in the drawer

Answer (score 0):

Few things you need to correct.

1. In the Left Drawer component, you can't directly use that props variable in the `v-model`. You need to create copy of that variable and watch that.

```
    props: ['leftDrawerOpen'],
    setup() {
      return {
        essentialLinks: linksList,
        drawe: ref(true)
      }
    },
    watch: {
      leftDrawerOpen: function () {
        console.log("In Watch")
        console.log(this.leftDrawerOpen)
        this.drawe = this.leftDrawerOpen
      }
    }
```

```
<q-drawer
    v-model="drawe"
    show-if-above
    bordered
  >
    <q-list>
      <q-item-label
        header
      >
        Essential Links
      </q-item-label>

    </q-list>
  </q-drawer>
```

2. In header Component you are missing `emits`

```
   emits:['toggleLeftDrawer']
```